# How to get account reference while using paypal future payment?

Tags: android, paypal

Hello I want to add more than one paypal accounts in my android application and user have to select from saved account at time of payment. For this I am using Future payment option  of paypal

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    PayPalAuthorization auth = data
            .getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
    if (auth != null) {
        try {
            String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();

            sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
        }
    }
} else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
} else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample",
            "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
}
}
```

in this way I am getting auth code but i also need some account reference to give account selection option to users. How can I get email reference with auth code or should I go thorough some other approach ?
Thanks!